# What's the field name required when save product price data in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, import-products

I have save custom product in magento 2 via my custom code. But when I save product the field qty not be save. please let me know in my data lost an field.

```
$new = array( "product" => Array(
            "name" => "Camera Car",
            "short_description" => "<p>highlights des</p>",
            "price" => 700,
            "type" => "simple",
            "status" => "1",
            "qty" => "60",
            "sku" => "v322",
            "attribute_set_id" =>"4",
            "quantity_and_stock_status" => Array(
                "is_in_stock" => "1",
                "qty" => "60"
            ),

            "website_id" => Array("1" => "1" ,"2" => "2"),

            "image" => "/h/t/camera-car-9749-01764366-4d34586f0dfb7371a939592effd332cd-catalog.jpg.tmp",
            "small_image" => "/h/t/camera-car-9749-01764366-4d34586f0dfb7371a939592effd332cd-catalog.jpg.tmp",
            "thumbnail" => "/h/t/camera-car-9749-01764366-4d34586f0dfb7371a939592effd332cd-catalog.jpg.tmp",
            "swatch_image" => "/h/t/camera-car-9749-01764366-4d34586f0dfb7371a939592effd332cd-catalog.jpg.tmp",
            "media_gallery" => Array(
                "images" => Array(
                    "1" => Array(
                        "position" => "1",
                        "file" => "/h/t/camera-car-9749-01764366-4d34586f0dfb7371a939592effd332cd-catalog.jpg.tmp",
                        "media_type" => "image",
                        "label" => '',
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ));
```

**Debug:**

> product->getPrice() // return 100  after call product->save() I check product->getPrice() // return nothing

Comment: Did you get my Below Answer??

Answer (score 0):

You Can Set or Save Product Details Like Below Code, So you don't need to Remember/Match Product Attributes .

```
  namespace YourPackage\YourModule\Controller\YourControllerClassDirectory;

  class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
  {
      public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
      ) 
      {
          $this->product = $product;  
          parent::__construct($context);
      }

      public function execute()
      {
            // Use Below line If you want to Edit/Update a Product Details , Other Wise Leave This Line for Inserting New Prod.
            $this->$product->load($product_id); 

            // By default 1
            $this->$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));

            // By default 1
            $this->$product->setAttributeSetId(1); 

            //By default simple product type
            $this->$product->setTypeId('simple'); 

            // Setting the time for Product Publication
            $this->$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime($setCreationTime));

            //Product Title
            $this->$product->setName($product_title);

            //Product Sku
            $this->$product->setSku($product_sku);    

            //Product Description
            $this->$product->setDescription($product_desc); 

            //Product Short Description
            $this->$product->setShortDescription($product_shortDesc); 

            //Product Categories should be array like $product_category_id = array(1,5,10);
            $this->$product->setCategoryIds($product_category_id);   

            // adding custom product attributes
            $this->$product->addData(  
                      array(
                          'custom_attribute_1'   => $custom_attribute_1,
                          'custom_attribute_2'   => $custom_attribute_2
                      )
                     );

            // Set Weight
            $this->$product->setWeight(0); 

            // Set Status 1 is for making product online
            $this->$product->setStatus(1); 

            // Set Tax Class Id
            $this->$product->setTaxClassId(0);  

            // Set Visibility 4 is for Catalog and Advance Search visibility
            $this->$product->setVisibility(4); 

            //Main Image
            $this->$product->setImage($product_main_banner); 

            //Small Image
            $this->$product->setSmallImage($product_small_banner);  

            //Thumb Image
            $this->$product->setThumbnail($product_thumb_banner); 

            //Price of Prodcut 
            $this->$product->setPrice(100) ; 

            //Meta Title
            $this->$product->setMetaTitle($product_Metatitle); 

            // Meta Keywords
            $this->$product->setMetaKeyword($product_MetaKeywords); 

            //Meta Desc
            $this->$product->setMetaDescription($product_Metadesc); 

            // Setting Product Stocks Details
            $this->$product->setStockData(  
                array('use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                    'min_sale_qty' => 1,
                    'max_sale_qty' => 2,
                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                    'qty' => 1
              )
            );      

            // Save Product
            $this->$product->save();  

            // Saved Product ID
            $get_product_id = $this->$product->getId(); 

      }

  }
```